# Multiple projects referencing MFC: "use mfc in a static library" vs "use mfc in a shared dll"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Using Visual Studio 2010 C++.  I have a project which uses MFC and I am statically linking to MFC.  I am in the process of trying to extract the non-GUI functionality into a separate static library project.  Because I want to use CStrings in my library project (debatable whether I should, but for the sake of argument) I now need to reference MFC in both my library and my exe projects.

My question is if I statically link with MFC in my library project *and* in my exe project, will I effectively have *two* copies of MFC linked in my final exe?  What if I added a third project so I had multiple libraries referencing mfc?  That sounds bad but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to link a library project, so there won't be an extra copy of MFC being linked in. You'll be creating a *dependency* on the MFC library from your static library, but that's normal. As long as the .exe project includes both libraries, everything will come out all right in the end.